# I executed query but error come like this

Tags: sql-server

```
INSERT INTO RPT(N5,T10,TXT1,T1,T2,T3,T6,N6,T7,T9,T8,N1,N2,N3,N4,N7,N8,TXT2)
    VALUES (
        (SELECT ISNULL((UNIT_COST*EX_RATE),0)
          FROM STOCKDETAILS
          WHERE PRODUCT_NO=N'AST20471' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),STOCK_DATE,120) < '2018-06-15'),
        (SELECT STOCK_JR
          FROM STOCKDETAILS
          WHERE PRODUCT_NO=N'AST20471' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),STOCK_DATE,120) < '2018-06-15'),
        '15-06-2018',
        '15-06-2018',
        N'AST20471',
        N'WASHER RUBBER OUTLET VALVE N123',
        'GR9553545',
        '2.466975', 
        (SELECT CATEGORY
          FROM PRODUCT
          WHERE PRODUCT_NO=N'AST20471'),
        (SELECT CATEGORY_MIDDLE
          FROM PRODUCT
          WHERE PRODUCT_NO=N'AST20471'),
        'MAIN',
        (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QTY_IN)-SUM(QTY_OUT),0)
          FROM STOCKDETAILS
          WHERE PRODUCT_NO=N'AST20471' AND CONVERT(varchar(10),STOCK_DATE,120) < '2018-06-15'),
        (SELECT SUM(QTY_IN)
          FROM STOCKDETAILS
          WHERE PRODUCT_NO=N'AST20471' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),STOCK_DATE,120) >= '2018-06-15' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),STOCK_DATE,120) <= '2018-06-15'),
        (SELECT SUM(QTY_OUT)
          FROM STOCKDETAILS
          WHERE PRODUCT_NO=N'AST20471' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),STOCK_DATE,120) >= '2018-06-15' AND CONVERT(varchar(10),STOCK_DATE,120) <= '2018-06-15'),
        (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(QTY_IN)-SUM(QTY_OUT),0)
          FROM STOCKDETAILS
          WHERE PRODUCT_NO=N'AST20471' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),STOCK_DATE,120) < ='2018-06-15'),
        '4.933950',
        '2',
        '15-06-2018 4:24:00 PM'
    )
```

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

coming this error please help

Comment: That wall of code in unreadable. Please read [ask]. Also, the error is pretty clear.

Comment: Error-------->Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. comeing this error please help

Comment: Please fix your formatting.  No one is going to try to read through that query.

Comment: Unless each of your sub query in values returns a single row this is not going to work. You should think about what to do when there are more rows from a sub query in values ... perhaps CROSS JOIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are trying to use sub query inside values and one or more of these is returning multiple rows as results and that is what is causing the error.
You can try to run each sub query one by one to see which all are giving multiple rows and then change your query accordingly or you can use a query like below which gives all possible result sets.
If each sub query returns one row then this will behave like values constructor

```
Insert into RPT(N5,T10,TXT1,T1,T2,T3,T6,N6,T7,T9,T8,N1,N2,N3,N4,N7,N8,TXT2)
SELECT N5,T10,TXT1,T1,T2,T3,T6,N6,T7,T9,T8,N1,N2,N3,N4,N7,N8,TXT2 from 
(
    select 
        N5=isnull((UNIT_COST*EX_RATE),0) 
    from STOCKDETAILS 
    where 
        PRODUCT_NO=N'AST20471' and
        CONVERT(varchar(10),STOCK_DATE,120) < '2018-06-15'
)t1

CROSS JOIN

(
    select 
        T10=STOCK_JR 
    from STOCKDETAILS 
    where 
        PRODUCT_NO=N'AST20471' 
    and  CONVERT(varchar(10),STOCK_DATE,120)
    < '2018-06-15'
) t2
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        TXT1='15-06-2018',
        T1='15-06-2018',
        T2=N'AST20471',
        T3=N'WASHER RUBBER OUTLET VALVE N123',
        T6='GR9553545',
        N6='2.466975',
        T8='MAIN',
        N7='4.933950',
        N8='2',
        TXT2='15-06-2018 4:24:00 PM'
)t3
CROSS JOIN
(
    select 
        T7=CATEGORY 
    from PRODUCT 
    where 
        PRODUCT_NO=N'AST20471'
)t4
CROSS JOIN
(
    select 
        t9=CATEGORY_MIDDLE 
    from PRODUCT 
    where 
        PRODUCT_NO=N'AST20471'
)t5
 CROSS JOIN
(
    select 
        N1=isnull(SUM(QTY_IN)-SUM(QTY_OUT),0) 
    from STOCKDETAILS 
    where 
        PRODUCT_NO=N'AST20471'
        and  CONVERT(varchar(10),STOCK_DATE,120) < '2018-06-15'
)t6
CROSS JOIN
(
    select 
        N2=SUM(QTY_IN) 
    from STOCKDETAILS
    where 
        PRODUCT_NO=N'AST20471' 
        and CONVERT(varchar(10),STOCK_DATE,120) >= '2018-06-15' 
        AND CONVERT(varchar(10),STOCK_DATE,120) <= '2018-06-15'
)t7

CROSS JOIN
(
    select 
        N3=SUM(QTY_OUT) 
    from STOCKDETAILS
    where 
        PRODUCT_NO=N'AST20471' 
        and CONVERT(varchar(10),STOCK_DATE,120) >= '2018-06-15' 
        AND CONVERT(varchar(10),STOCK_DATE,120) <= '2018-06-15'
)t8

CROSS JOIN
(
    select 
        n4=isnull(SUM(QTY_IN)-SUM(QTY_OUT),0)
    from STOCKDETAILS 
    where 
        PRODUCT_NO=N'AST20471' 
        and CONVERT(varchar(10),STOCK_DATE,120)< ='2018-06-15'
)t9
```